# Convert Script to linux

Tags: bash

Can someone help to convert this DOS script to bash.
I tried but i didn't really succeed

```
set DownloadPath="/volume1/various/temp"
set CorruptFilePath=/volume1/various/!corrupt
set ErrorReport=/volume1/various/Corrupt files.txt
pushd %DownloadPath%
for /r %%i in (*.rar;) do (
    "unrar.exe" t "%%i"
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo %%i>>%ErrorReport% & copy "%%i" %CorruptFilePath%
)
popd
```

Can someone help me out, many thanks

Requested to update the question so i did, but the script is already convert as seen below, only missing a small part about maxdir depth

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is an assignment rather than a question. What have you tried so far? What problems did you face?

Comment: You should add some explanations about the syntax of the script above, after all not everyone know this. I want to help you but I got stuck with the syntax.

Comment: Do you have a linux version of `unrar.exe`?  Where is the documentation/spec for this script?  If you don't have one then write it then implement that in `bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your script tests integrity of every `.rar` file in a given folder (including subfolders), reports every failure in an error log and copies the failed `.rar` files to a separate folder.

A straightforward port to Bash would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DownloadPath="/volume1/various/temp"
CorruptFilePath="/volume1/various/!corrupt"
ErrorReport="/volume1/various/Corrupt files.txt"

cd "$DownloadPath"
shopt -s globstar
for r in **/*.rar; do
        unrar t "$r" || { echo "$r" >> "$ErrorReport" && cp -p "$r" "$CorruptFilePath"; }
done
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested the script. Please feel free to do so yourself.

Comment: That should probably be `for r in **/*.rar`.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks, I didn't pay attention to `/r` indeed. Adjusted my answer. Who knows, some day somebody may benefit from it.

Comment: @Ruud/Melpomene thanks :) it works but depending on the folder depth *.rar for in the main folder **/*.rar in 1 folder deep, how can i check multiple levels deep?

Comment: How can i get each new enty in the text file on a new line now it doesn't work everything goes on the same line, i tried \n and printf but somehow it didn't work. Opening the text file in VI

Comment: forget the next line as i fixed itunrar t "$r" || { printf "\n $r" >> "$ErrorReport" && cp -p "$r" "$CorruptFilePath", sorry no idea how to get it here in a nice gray square so it looks good

Comment: @Marco Thank you for the edit. BTW you can surround code snippets with backticks (`\``). See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: final question i want to move the files on some folders  `unrar t "$r" || { printf "\n$r" >> "$ErrorReport" && mv -f "$r" "$CorruptFilePath/"$r""/; }` this doesn't work

Comment: `unrar t "$r" || { printf "\n$r" >> "$ErrorReport" && mv -f "$r" "$CorruptFilePath/"$r""/;`